# Error in phpmyadmin and runs fine in local host

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing an sp,i want to use limit inside an insert query.But the value of the limit is varying one.So i used a variable. It runs fine in my local host as its version is 5.6.14 .When i tried to run the same sp in  phpmyadmin(version 5.1.54-1ubuntu4 ) it cause an error as variable in a limit is not supported in older versions.
I am getting error in the following query

```
    insert into tmp_table_rule2 (reward_id) 
    select 
        (reward_id) 
    from 
       vbw_redemptions 
   order  by redemption_id desc limit rule2_redemption_count;
```

Comment: Use dynamic SQL to prepare the query.

Comment: Can you give me any idea? @Barmar

Answer (score 3):

Use a prepared statement:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('
    insert into tmp_table_rule2 (reward_id) 
    select 
        (reward_id) 
    from 
       vbw_redemptions 
    order  by redemption_id desc limit ', rule2_redemption_count);
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
```

Comment: what does this code do ? @barmar. Why i am asking because i have this issues in many part of my sp

Comment: It uses `CONCAT` to create a string containing the SQL query you want to execute. Then it executes it.

Comment: Okay Barmar ,Thanks for the concern :) I ll try this and let you know if am facing issues

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted your question? I don't think I did.